# How to pass a boolean to a method with a variable name

Tags: groovy

I have a method such as this

```
def uploadFile(String fileName, boolean performCleanup = false) {
   //upload file
   if (performCleanup == true) {
       //delete local file
   }
}
```

I call this method in two ways:

1. `uploadFile("/some/path/to/file.txt")`
2. `uploadFile("/some/path/to/file.txt", true)`

In the second case, for better readability, I would like to pass a variable name that would suggest what the significance of passing `true` is.

Something like, `uploadFile("/some/path/to/file.txt", performCleanup: true")`

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-named-parameters-are.html) post will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By introducing and extra closure you can create a nicely readable micro DSL:

```
def performCleanup = {
  println "cleanup $it" //delete local file
}
def upload(fileName) {
  println "upload file $fileName" //upload file
  [then: { action ->
    action(fileName)
  }]
}

upload "path"
upload "path" then performCleanup
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Map` to simulate named args:

```
def uploadFile(Map args) {
   String fileName = args.fileName

   // will default to false if omitted
   boolean performCleanup = args.performCleanup

   //upload file
   if (performCleanup == true) {
       //delete local file
   }
}
```

You can then call the method using

```
uploadFile(fileName: "/some/path/to/file.txt")
uploadFile(fileName: "/some/path/to/file.txt", performCleanup: true)
```

This style has some pros and cons compared to the more typical style (wherein each value is passed as a separate argument):

- Improved call site readability
- Diminished declaration site readability
- Flexibility, e.g. you can add/remove args to the method without updating each caller
- Diminished compile-time safety, e.g. even if static compilation is enabled, you can't tell whether each caller is providing the required arguments

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another way to use it in a DSL-ish way, by returning a map which can responds to `performCleanup`:

```
def uploadFile(String fileName) {
    //upload file
    println "uploading file"

    [performCleanup: { 
        //delete local file
        println "cleaning up" 
    }]
}

uploadFile 'file' performCleanup()
```

Output:

```
$ groovy Clean.groovy 
uploading file
cleaning up
```

By not calling `performCleanup()` after, it doesn't happen:

```
uploadFile 'file'
```

Output:

```
$ groovy Clean.groovy 
uploading file
```